# Angular API calls and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angular app and having a difficult time with one seemly simple operation. Basically, I'm making a call to the soundcloud api, grabbing my tracks, then looping through those tracks and grabbing the iframe embed object, injecting that into the tracks object then sending that whole thing as a promise to be resolved and stored in a $scope.soundcloud object. Just fyi, the second SC call is necessary to generate the widget html. I wish it wasn't but it is hah.

This all happends as it should and i can see the object in $scope. My template picks up the initial data (main track data), and console.logging the object shows the track and embed data, but the template NEVER sees the embed data.

So, fundamentally, How do I get my template to see the embed data, so i can use it with a directive or ng-bind-html? Below is all my code, please ask if you need any more information! Thank you all very much.

HTML

```
<div class="track" ng-repeat="track in soundcloud.tracks">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="app/img/loading.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="back" ng-bind-html="{{track.oembed}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular Service

```
        getTracks: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;

            SC.get("/me/tracks", function(tracks){
                $.each(tracks, function(k, v){
                    if(v.sharing != 'private'){
                        SC.oEmbed(v.uri, function(oembed){

                            v.oembed = $sce.trustAsHtml(oembed.html);

                        });
                    } else {
                        v.oembed = null;
                    }
                });
                deferred.resolve(tracks);
            });


            return $q.all({tracks: promise});
        }
```

Angular Controller

```
    .controller("GridCtrl", ['$scope', 'Soundcloud', function($scope, Soundcloud){

        // Init the Soundcloud SDK config
        Soundcloud.initialize();

        // Get the tracks from soundcloud
        Soundcloud.getTracks().then(function success(results){

            // Store tracks in the $scope
            $scope.soundcloud = results;
            console.log(results);

        });


    }]);
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping an $apply? `$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.soundcloud = results; });`?

Comment: I had before but not how you wrote it, but i each time i get "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress". Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like something else is wrong, try turning off the $sceProvider and see if the issue comes from there?

Comment: @ShanRobertson does the `console.log(results)` part work? Does it log anything there?

Comment: Another note, I'm assuming SC.get also returns a promise, don't use `$q.defer()` when already working with a promise - see https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#wiki-the-deferred-anti-pattern

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yep the results logs the object with the oembed property. Also, the oembed property's value is "TrustedValueHolderType" if that tells you anything

Comment: @AlexandrinRus I took $sce out of the factory's function and just got $sce is undefined... unless i misinterpreted what you meant?

Comment: In the config stage of the app inject $sceProvider, and add the line $sceProvider.enabled(false). Then don't use the $sce service at all inside the factory anymore.

Comment: A quick fix you could do if you do not find the spurce of the problem would be to create a directive that you expose the oembed property to and use elem.replaceWith(oembed) in the link function.

Comment: @AlexandrinRus I've tried accessing scope from the directive to no avail, and if i try to get the oembed property from a data binding attribute it just gives me the {{track.oembed}}

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not sure if it does, i certainly started without promises but moved to using them because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a directive like this:

```
app.module('yourModule').directive('embedTrack', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.replaceWith(scope.track.oembed);
    };
});
```

You then use it like this:

```
<div class="track" ng-repeat="track in soundcloud.tracks">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="app/img/loading.gif" />
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <div embed-track></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you want to pass it as an attribute to the directive, you need to use attr.$observe to make sure you get the value after the interpolation.

`<div embed-track={{ track.oembed }}></div>`

The directive would then be:

```
app.module('yourModule').directive('embedTrack', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        attr.$observe('embedTrack', function(value) {
            elem.replaceWith(value);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll try this out as soon as I get home from work today, this $observe function looks like something I should know about in this case, will read up on it.

Comment: So i got this directive working, but only with the uri from the original data, which i could always see...  still not able to see the oembed prop but I think i'm going to move on, as this works for now... Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It may be possible you have to change `v.oembed = $sce.trustAsHtml(oembed.html);` to `v.oembed = oembed.html;` in your service to get it working using the `oembed` attribute because of the way this directive works.